# jQuery group elements by name with count

Tags: jquery, list, sorting, count

I have a large list of names from a database that I want to filter and give a count for a specific name value - in this case 'Anonymous'.

For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>Johnny Ace</li>
    <li>Mary Adams</li>
    <li>Bob Allen</li>
    <li>Anonymous</li>
    <li>Anonymous</li>
    <li>Anonymous</li>
    <li>Anonymous</li>
    <li>Anonymous</li>
    <li>David Brown</li>
    <li>Sue Smith</li>
    <li>John Williams</li>
</ul>
```

I want the result to be:

```
<ul>
    <li>Johnny Ace</li>
    <li>Mary Adams</li>
    <li>Bob Allen</li>
    <li>Anonymous (5)</li>
    <li>David Brown</li>
    <li>Sue Smith</li>
    <li>John Williams</li>
</ul>
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: This should normally be done server side, for obvious efficiency reasons.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ALM2k/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this using `:contains()` to get the length and remove all but the first one, and then set the text

```
var count=$('ul li:contains("Anonymous")').length;
$('ul li:contains("Anonymous")').not(':first').remove().end().text("Anonymous("+count+")");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TYQZV/)

Answer (score 0):

Loops might be easy as well, works for all elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/N6wSf/16/

```
var categories = {},
    category;
$('ul li').each(function(i, el){
    category = $(el).text();
    if (categories.hasOwnProperty(category)) {
        categories[category] += 1;
    } else {
        categories[category] = 1;
    }
});

$('ul').empty();
// print results
for(var key in categories){
    $('ul').append('<li>' + key + ' (' + categories[key] + ')</li>');
}
```